# DataGridView.Refresh throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a `DataGridView` with a number of "custom" button columns. All of a sudden, I've noticed that, when I action the code for one of the buttons (but not for any of the others), I get an unhandled exception when I attempt to refresh the DGV.

Here is the code in question :

```
Private Sub editAction(clickedButton As DataGridViewCustomButtonCell)
    Try
        Dim activeRow As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows(clickedButton.RowIndex)
        Select Case clickedButton.Value
            Case True
                ' Entering Edit mode
                activeRow.Cells(statusColumn.Index).Value = "Editing"

            Case False
                ' Exiting Edit mode
                If activeRow.Cells(idColumn.Index).Value = -1 Then
                    activeRow.Cells(statusColumn.Index).Value = "Copy"
                ElseIf activeRow.Cells(idColumn.Index).Value = -2 Then
                    activeRow.Cells(statusColumn.Index).Value = "New"
                Else
                    activeRow.Cells(statusColumn.Index).Value = ""
                End If

        End Select
        dgv.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the exception :

> System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object'

This was working fine a couple of days ago, and I was working on something else when suddenly this exception started appearing, but I can't figure out what I could have changed to suddenly cause it? Like I say, the other buttons work fine, and they all fire the same `.Refresh` method when their code has completed. So not sure why this particular one is suddenly an issue?

None of the variables in the sub are null, per watches, nor the DGV itself. And the exception isn't giving me much detail as to what it is exactly that might be null such that it's causing a problem?

(There's no `InnerException` but here is the `StackTrace` if it's any use - makes no sense to me)

> at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.PaintPrivate(Graphics
> graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex,
> DataGridViewElementStates cellState, Object formattedValue, String
> errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
> DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
> DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts, Boolean computeContentBounds,
> Boolean computeErrorIconBounds, Boolean paint)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Paint(Graphics graphics,
> Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex,
> DataGridViewElementStates cellState, Object value, Object
> formattedValue, String errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
> DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
> DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.PaintWork(Graphics graphics,
> Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex,
> DataGridViewElementStates cellState, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
> DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
> DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.PaintCells(Graphics graphics,
> Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex,
> DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow,
> Boolean isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics,
> Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex,
> DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow,
> Boolean isLastVisibleRow)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle
> boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle
> gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded,
> Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
> Int16 layer)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Only thing I can think of is that the `Protected Overrides Sub Paint` in the custom button cell class is falling over but this code has remained the exact same throughout so I don't know why it might suddenly be an issue?

```
Public Class DataGridViewCustomButtonCell
    Inherits DataGridViewButtonCell

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim cell As DataGridViewCustomButtonCell = CType(MyBase.Clone(), DataGridViewCustomButtonCell)
        cell.IsEnabled = Me.IsEnabled
        Return cell
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Me.isEnabledValue = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(ByVal graphics As Graphics,
        ByVal clipBounds As Rectangle, ByVal cellBounds As Rectangle,
        ByVal rowIndex As Integer,
        ByVal elementState As DataGridViewElementStates,
        ByVal value As Object, ByVal formattedValue As Object,
        ByVal errorText As String,
        ByVal cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle,
        ByVal advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle,
        ByVal paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)

        ' Draw the background of the cell, if specified.
        If (paintParts And DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) = DataGridViewPaintParts.Background Then
            Dim cellBackground As New SolidBrush(IIf(Me.isToggleValue AndAlso Me.isPressedValue, Color.Black, cellStyle.BackColor))
            graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds)
            cellBackground.Dispose()
        End If

        ' Draw the cell borders, if specified.
        If (paintParts And DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) = DataGridViewPaintParts.Border Then
            PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle)
        End If

        ' Calculate the area in which to draw the button.
        Dim buttonArea As Rectangle = cellBounds
        Dim buttonAdjustment As Rectangle = Me.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle)
        buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X
        buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y
        buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height
        buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width

        ' Calculate the area in which to draw the image.
        Dim imagearea As Rectangle = New Rectangle(buttonArea.X + 5, buttonArea.Y + 5, buttonArea.Width - 10, buttonArea.Height - 10)

        ' Draw the button
        If enabledImage Is Nothing Then enabledImage = buttonImagesEnabled(Me.OwningColumn.Index)
        If disabledImage Is Nothing Then disabledImage = buttonImagesDisabled(Me.OwningColumn.Index)

        If enabledImage IsNot Nothing AndAlso disabledImage IsNot Nothing Then
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea, IIf(Me.isEnabledValue, enabledImage, disabledImage), imagearea, False, IIf(Me.isEnabledValue, IIf(Me.isPressedValue, PushButtonState.Pressed, PushButtonState.Normal), PushButtonState.Disabled))
        Else
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea, IIf(Me.isEnabledValue, IIf(Me.isPressedValue, PushButtonState.Pressed, PushButtonState.Normal), PushButtonState.Disabled))
        End If

        Me.ToolTipText = ""

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: As a slight aside, might pay to review you usage of dgv.Refresh().  This does not refresh the data as I suspect you might be expecting.  This forcing a re-paint of the control which  will be causing the Paint event to fire when perhaps it doesn't need to

Comment: Thanks @Hursey - no, am not expecting it to refresh data, merely fire the .CellFormatting event where I have code to format the grid according to various criteria. Valid point, and thanks, but not the issue in this particular scenario...

Comment: Aargh - figured it out after hours of line-by-line debugging... Per previous comment, I was forcing the `.CellFormatting` event to fire. Within that code, I was (for reasons known only to myself circa two days ago...) calling a separate function which was modifying one of the cells by disposing and recreating it, thus creating the null reference. Shouldn't have been in there, I was basically trying to paint a chair while standing on top of it. Silly mistake, function call has been suitably moved to where it should be, I have given myself the proverbial smack on the wrist for being dumb, sorry

Comment: Glad to hear you've got is sorted.  perhaps you could either post your solution as an accepted answer?

Comment: I think the problem I created (i.e. disposing a grid element and replacing it with a bespoke element, during a `.CellFormatting` event) is probably quite niche? Also, the issue wasn't with any of the code I had posted; it was in the `.CellFormatting` event handler which was triggered by the `.Refresh` call. I would imagine if anybody else gets this kind of problem, the comments here would be sufficient to help them check the events subsequent to `.Refresh` - my specific code wouldn't necessarily be relevant?